# Jquery UI draggable option snap, how to position it correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

how can I position the draggable elements in center of the snap ?

my code lools like this:

```
$(".match_task_draggable").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: $('.match_task_draggable').parent('div').parent('div'),
    scroll: false,
    snap: ".match_task_drop" });
```

Result is this:

[image]

The Snap element is fixed at top or bottom of the target. How can I position it vertically ?

Comment: Provide a fiddle please! :)

Comment: its difficult to extract the code, the site is generated from about 10 other pages

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: dosn't work in js fiddle ... https://jsfiddle.net/wjgo97rf/

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box functionality for this. You can try to make it work with `grid` if your elements' sizes permit it, or (the more flexible way) with adding "invisible" elements to snap to